# Access To Moderator Tools page has an outdated image

Tags: support

Very minor issue. If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

you'll see this image

[image]

which is not how the new top bar looks like.

Comment: It's not in the top bar, it's in the /review page https://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: My bad. I'm new to the moderator tools and whatnot. Thank you Bhargav.

Comment: Sorry for that edit, completely misunderstood it.

Comment: It *is* different ('Review' is blue now, but maybe it always was), but not that this image is used throughout the entire Stack Exchange network. Color differences are to be expected, and I'm casting the final close vote as a 'mental typo'. Congratulations on joining the 10k club and enjoy your newly obtained privileges!

Comment: Eh ... `s/not/note/`

Comment: @glor that image is from meta.so